# Javascript invalid date in iOS/Android 2.2

Tags: javascript, android, ios, date

I have this string containing a date I need to parse to get a Date javascript object. It works if I execute the code in a PC browser but gives me an invalid date if I run the web page in a iOS (tried iPhone 4.3) and Android 2.2 emulator.

```
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var date = new Date('2011-03-04T08:14:00+01:00');
  $('#test').html(date.toString());
});
</script>
<div id="test"></div>
</html>
</body>
```

Does anybody know what may be wrong? I can always parse the date manually (considering it'll always be in the same format) but anyways it seems like a strage problem to me.

Cheers!

Comment: Where does the date come from?  Do you control its format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date actually **is** invalid:

```
tjwebb@latitude:~$ rhino
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2010 09 15
js> var date = new Date('2011-03-04T08:14:00+01:00');
js> date.toString();
Invalid Date
js>
```

This is using Rhino, Mozilla's javascript engine, which is about as "standard" as it gets.

-tjw

Comment: Ok, will do the manual parsing approach then. Guess the Android/iOS browsers are more stric that the PC versions.

Comment: How is it that Javascript has been around for decades and there is still no consensus/standardization regarding dates? My brain melts!