# Why I obtain an "Invalid Date" error when I try to set a Date object into a JS script performed in Rhino?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, wso2-esb

I am not so into JavaScript and I have a huge problem trying to perform a simple JavaScript code into **Rhino** (https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Rhino) that is a JavaScript implementation that allows to perform JS code into a Java application. In my specific case **Rhino** is embedded into **WSO2 ESB** (an ESB tool developed in Java).

I can perform my JS code into my Java\WSO2 ESB application but I am experiencing some problem trying to create a JavaScript **Date** object. In this case it can't work.

If in my JS code I have something like:

```
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date('2017-11-09 06:00:00');
```

it works fine if I perfom it into the browser but performing it into **Rhino** I obtain the following error message into the Java console:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-09 15:55:43,610]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext} -  dateCurrentOriginalForecast: Invalid Date {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-11-09 15:55:43,610] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: RangeError: Date is invalid. (<Unknown Source>#139) in <Unknown Source> at line number 139
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:345)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:233)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:260)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:775)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: RangeError: Date is invalid. (<Unknown Source>#139)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate.toISOString(NativeDate.java:398)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeDate.execIdCall(NativeDate.java:384)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__1177._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:139)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__1177.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__1177.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__1177.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        ... 16 more
```

I have also tried other format such as:

```
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date('2017-11-09 06:00:00');
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date('2017-11-09T06:00:00.000Z');
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date('2017-11-09T06:00:00');
var dateCurrentOriginalForecast = new Date('2017-11-09T06:00:00T');
```

but I still obtain the same error.

Why? What is the problem? What am I missing? What is a correct date format that is ok for Rhino?

Something similar related to Date objects and Rhino is here but there is not a solution: [Javascript invalid date in iOS/Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392729/javascript-invalid-date-in-ios-android-2-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectivly it's strange....

Try using explicit date part :

```
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])

new Date('2017','11','09','06','00','00')
```

Answer (score 1):

It has a different implementation of `Date`. If `Date.parse` of the string returns `NaN` then the string is not interpreted as a valid date and calls of `new Date(string)` will return a `date` but `InvalidDate`.

Split the string dates on its parts and set them separately, or uild string dates that are respecting the `Date` requirements.

Comment: But why they have implemented a different version of the Date object? It is a JavaScript implementation on Java...there is a reason for this different version? This cause a lot of incompatibility.

Comment: @AndreaNobili why IE js is diffferent than Chrome js :)